Unable to Use External Crates (e.g., `orao_solana_vrf`) in Solana Playground
I am developing a Solana smart contract and am currently using the Solana Playground environment for testing and development. However, I am encountering an issue where I am unable to use the crate orao_solana_vrf in the Playground environment. The error message I am seeing is:
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `orao_solana_vrf`
 --> src/misc.rs:5:5
  |
5 | use orao_solana_vrf::state::RandomnessAccountData;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `orao_solana_vrf`

When trying to import the crate, the Playground fails to resolve it. As the Playground doesn’t seem to support running cargo commands or managing external dependencies like a local setup, I'm unsure how to proceed.
What I've tried:

I tried modifying the Cargo.toml locally, but I cannot run cargo commands in the Playground.

Questions:

Is there any way to use external crates like orao_solana_vrf in Solana Playground, or is this environment limited to only the built-in libraries?
If not, what is the best approach to develop and test Solana smart contracts that depend on external crates like orao_solana_vrf?


It seems that Orao isn't supported on Solana Playground.
The readme suggests opening an issue to request more crates.

You can open an issue to request more crates (i.e orao-vrf).

These are the supported crates on Solana Playground



Crate
Version




anchor-lang
0.29.0


anchor-spl
0.29.0


arrayref
0.3.7


borsh
0.10.3


borsh-derive
0.10.3


bytemuck
1.14.0


bytemuck_derive
1.5.0


mpl-bubblegum
1.0.0


mpl-token-auth-rules
1.4.3


mpl-token-metadata
3.2.3


num-derive
0.4.0


num-traits
0.2.16


pyth-sdk
0.8.0


pyth-sdk-solana
0.8.0


serde
1.0.193


solana-program
1.16.24


spl-account-compression
0.2.0


spl-associated-token-account
2.2.0


spl-pod
0.1.0


spl-tlv-account-resolution
0.4.0


spl-token
4.0.0


spl-token-2022
0.9.0


spl-token-metadata-interface
0.2.0


spl-transfer-hook-interface
0.3.0


spl-type-length-value
0.3.0


switchboard-solana
0.29.79


switchboard-v2
0.4.0


thiserror
1.0.48



